# How do I subset the columns of a dataframe based on the index of another dataframe?

Tags: pandas

The rows of `clin.index` (row length = 81) is a subset of the columns of `common_mrna` (col length = 151). I want to keep the columns of `common_mrna` only if the column names match to the row values of `clin` dataframe.

My code failed to reduce the number of columns in `common_mrna` to 81.

```
import pandas as pd

common_mrna = common_mrna.set_index("Hugo_Symbol")
mrna_val = {}
for colnames, val in common_mrna.iteritems():
  for i, rows in clin.iterrows():
    if [[common_mrna.columns == i] == "TRUE"]:
      mrna_val = np.append(mrna_val, val)

mrna = np.concatenate(mrna_val, axis=0)
```

`common_mrna`

| Hugo_Symbol | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Second | 5 | row | 6 | 7 |

`clin`

|  | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| D | 30 |

desired output

| Hugo_Symbol | A | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 4 |
| Second | 5 | 7 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `reindex`:

```
common_mrna.reindex(clin.index, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        A  D
First   1  4
Second  5  7
```

---

Update, IIUC:

```
common_mrna.set_index('Hugo_Symbol').reindex(clin.index, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: I've updated the question. The `common_mrna` dataframe has a `Hugo_Symbol` index column, which I want to retain in the new dataframe. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @melolili If I understand you correctly, try the updated solution.

Comment: I think you should further drop the NaN column if `clin` index column contains column not in `common_mrna` columns.

Answer (score 0):

IUUC, you can select the rows of `A header` in `clin` found in `common_mrna` columns and add the first column of `common_mrna`

```py
cols = clin.loc[clin.index.isin(common_mrna.columns)].index.tolist()
# or with set
cols = list(sorted(set(clin.index.tolist()) & set(common_mrna.columns), key=common_mrna.columns.tolist().index))

out = common_mrna[['Hugo_Symbol'] + cols]
```

```
print(out)

  Hugo_Symbol  A  D
0       First  1  4
1      Second  5  7
```

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. The "A header" column is actually the index. When I replace "A header" with index, your code failed. Please see the updated question.